# can we copy data from on column to another with different datatypes?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to do this but I am not sure if it is possible or not.

I am trying to copy data of one `tblRecords1(nvarchar) of table1 to tblRecords(bigint)` of another table using convert function.

But it is giving error. Is it possible to do so or not?

This is ensured that values in tblRecords1 are all numeric values.

**update**

i am doing it as follow:

`INSERT INTO tblRecords (current_job_title,Highest_Education_Stream)
 SELECT convert(bigint,current_job_title),convert(bigint,Highest_Education_Stream)
FROM tblRecords1`

so what wrong am i doing?

**update**
i forgot about null values. they were creating problem. so i got it done by as follow:

```
INSERT INTO tblRecords (current_job_title,Highest_Education_Stream)

 SELECT current_job_title = case when current_job_title is null then 0 else convert(bigint,current_job_title) end,
               Highest_Education_Stream=case when Highest_Education_Streamis null then 0 else convert(bigint,current_job_title) end,
 FROM tblRecords1
```

Comment: Show your code and tell us what error you are getting. But yes it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do it as given below

> INSERT INTO tblRecords (current_job_title,Highest_Education_Stream) 
>   SELECT cast(bigint as "datatype of current_job_title"), cast(bigint
>   as "datatype of Highest_Education_Stream") FROM tblRecords1

replace "datatype of current_job_title" and "datatype of Highest_Education_Stream" with actual datatype
and for null checking use

> ISNULL(Variable,0)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert, providing the type you are converting from can sensibly match the type it's converting to.  So you could do this:

```
declare @from varchar(20) = '1000000'
declare @to bigint

select @to = convert(bigint, @from)
select @to
```

See [CAST and CONVERT on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)