# DB2SQL copy data from one column to another in different datatype

Tags: sql, db2

May i know is it possible to copy data from one column to another in different data type?

My current TB_TEST records.

- RENEWAL_NO data type VARCHAR (10)
- RENEWAL_NO2 data type INTERGER

### SQL table

RENEWAL_NO  | RENEWAL_NO2 
!---------------------!-----------------------!

1111
        2222
        3333
        4444
        5555
        6666

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can make use of typecasting in your update/insert query:

Method1: db2 "`select cast(column_name as datatype) from table_name`"

Or

Method2: db2 "`select datatype(column_name) from table_name`"

Look for similar example in sql server here:

[can we copy data from on column to another with different datatypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11882104/can-we-copy-data-from-on-column-to-another-with-different-datatypes/11884201#11884201)

For Typecasting in DB2 refer:

http://www.dbatodba.com/db2/how-to-do/how-to-convert-data-types-on-db2/